# Obtaining locations around user API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, swift

I'm attempting to retrieve locations around a user upon retrieving their current location. Is anyone familiar with which API's/Frameworks are best to accomplish this? I've tried Foursquare2 but it seems that half the locations don't return addresses. I need a better API to use, preferably one that will return addresses, and can't seem to find any others. I came across Google Places, but it appears to be in beta and not available unless I submit a form and wait. Is there a way to do this with Google Maps or the Facebook graph perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which device you use. For example if you want to retrieve location data from android use [**this api**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location), for an ios device, use read the my location section in [**this doc**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map). Hope this gives you some idea.